# SQL Server How to UPDATE with SELECT and GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, sql-update

Our team uses SQL Server and I wanted to use aggregate function to update one of the columns for the NEW values that are being inserted existing table.

Below is the existing table and values in it.

```
CREATE TABLE CARS 
(
   ID INT NOT NULL,
   carCompany VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   feature VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   sequence INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO CARS VALUES (1, 'Toyota', 'Auto transmission', 1); 
INSERT INTO CARS VALUES (2, 'BMW', 'Keyless Entry system', 1);
INSERT INTO CARS VALUES (3, 'Toyota', 'Power Steering', 2); 
INSERT INTO CARS VALUES (4, 'Tesla', 'Auto transmission', 1); 
INSERT INTO CARS VALUES (5, 'BMW', 'Auto transmission', 2);
INSERT INTO CARS VALUES (6, 'Tesla', 'Keyless Entry system', 2);
INSERT INTO CARS VALUES (7, 'BMW', 'Power Steering', 3);
```

Requirement came in to 'Auto Pilot' for BMW and Tesla only with sequence column incremented in the same carCompany group. Since, Insert statement was easier, I just inserted records and struggling to get the Update statement right.

```
INSERT INTO CARS VALUES (8, 'Tesla', 'Auto Pilot', 0);
INSERT INTO CARS VALUES (9, 'BMW', 'Auto Pilot', 0);
```

Below `UPDATE` statement is INCORRECT. Kindly help here.

```
UPDATE c1 
SET c1.sequence = d.sq
FROM 
    (SELECT MAX(c2.sequence) + 1 AS sq 
     FROM CARS c2 
     WHERE c2.carCompany = c1.carCompany 
     GROUP BY c2.carCompany) d
WHERE c1.sequence = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, just move the correlated subquery into the SET statement:

```
UPDATE c1 
    SET c1.sequence = (SELECT max(fc2.sequence) + 1 as sq FROM CARS c2 WHERE c2.carCompany = c1.carCompany GROUP BY c2.carCompany)
FROM CARS c1
WHERE c1.sequence = 0
```

But note that this only works if there's only one new record for that car company. I.e., if you had two new Tesla features they'd both be set to 2. You can use a CTE with the RANK function to allow for any number of new values:

```
WITH NewSequences
AS (
SELECT id, RANK()OVER(PARTITION BY c1.carCompany ORDER BY id) + (SELECT max(fc2.sequence) + 1 as sq FROM CARS c2 WHERE c2.carCompany = c1.carCompany GROUP BY c2.carCompany) AS NewSeq
FROM CARS
WHERE c1.[sequence] = 0
)
UPDATE c1 
    SET c1.sequence = n.NewSeq
FROM CARS c1
    INNER JOIN NewSequences n
        ON c1.id = NewSequences.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the next sequence number, you are very close with your query:

```
UPDATE cars 
    SET sequence = d.sq
FROM (SELECT max(c2.sequence) + 1 as sq
      FROM CARS c2 
      GROUP BY c2.carCompany
     ) c2
     ON c2.carCompany = c1.carCompany
WHERE sequence = 0;
```

Note:  I don't think this does what you want if you have inserted multiple rows with the same company.  Presumably, you want them to have different values, so you would use:

```
with toupdate as (
      select c.*,
             max(c.sequence) over (partition by carcompany) as max_sequence,
             row_number() over (partition by carcompany order by id) as seqnum
      from cars c
     )
update toupdate
    set sequence = max_sequence + seqnum
    where sequence = 0;
```

However, pre-calculating this value seems quite unnecessary when you can just use:

```
select c.*,
       row_number() over (partition by carCompany order by id) as seq
from cars c;
```

I don't see a reason to store this value.